# window.location.href not get all href?

Tags: javascript, path, href, searchbar, window.location

i used `var x = window.location.href` on big website project but it not get all href
for example:
in searchbar in browser https://www.example.com/script/album
but when get it by href like this show: https://www.example.com/script/ without "/album"
any solution?

note: when i open /album in website.. i think the website not open new page but it opened inside same page...but location in searchbar changed
.....................
..................
...............
SOLVED by: `window.document.referrer`

Comment: have you check pathname

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.